# Merging two data frames without repetition using unique ID's

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two data frames. The first one has less rows (2354), one unique ID, and two repeated ID's (CVE_MUN and CVE_ENT), these two are geographical identifiers.

```
# A tibble: 2,354 x 6
   CLAVE   NOMBRE       CVE_ENT `ENTIDAD FEDERATIVA~ CVE_MUN `MUNICIPIO (INEG~
   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>            
 1 03AGN-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 2 03AGO-~ Agostaderito       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 3 03AGP-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 4 03AGS-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 5 03AIS-~ Alfa Nissan        1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 6 03ALF-~ Nissan Mexi~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 7 03APT-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 8 03ASS-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
 9 03ASU-~ Asuncion           1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES   
10 03AYU-~ Ayuntamiento       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES
```

So I have 26 different ID's (CLAVE) in a certain area (CVE_ENT:1, CVE_MUN: 1), 3 ID's in an other area (CVE_ENT:1, CVE_MUN:2), etc

```
CVE_ENT    CVE_MUN    Freq
 1            1        26
 1            2        3
 1            3        2
 1            5        3
 1            6        1
 1            7        1
 1            9        1
 1           10        2
 1           11        2
```

I want to map all the ID's, so I am trying to merge it to a very detailed geographical data frame. This data frame has 299615 rows, each "MAPA" row has a unique long,lat coordinates.

```
      MAPA CVE_ENT        NOM_ENT NOM_ABR CVE_MUN        NOM_MUN CVE_LOC
1  10010001       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES       1
2  10010094       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES      94
3  10010096       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES      96
4  10010100       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     100
5  10010102       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     102
6  10010104       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     104
7  10010106       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     106
8  10010112       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     112
9  10010113       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     113
10 10010120       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     120
11 10010121       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     121
12 10010125       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     125
13 10010126       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     126
14 10010127       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     127
15 10010128       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     128
16 10010135       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     135
17 10010138       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     138
18 10010139       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     139
19 10010141       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     141
20 10010144       1 AGUASCALIENTES    AGS.       1 AGUASCALIENTES     144
```

Again, I have CVE_ENT and CVE_MUN but this time they are repeated many more times than with my first data frame.

```
CVE_ENT    CVE_MUN    Freq
 1           1         725
 1           2         242
 1           3         293
 1           4         94
```

What I want is to merge df1 given CVE_ENT and CVE_MUN with df2 without repeating MAPA. That is, that "CLAVE" gets merge to a different "MAPA" given CVE_ENT and CVE_MUN. Ideally, df1 will merge the first 26 CVE_ENT=1 and CVE_MUN=1 to the first 26 CVE_ENT=1 and CVE_MUN=1 of df2.

So far I have tried left_join and filtering by "CLAVE" but I'm getting "MAPA" repeated so again, I don't have a unique geographical long, lat.

```
Coord<-left_join(df1,df2,by=c("CVE_ENT","CVE_MUN"))
DT <- Coord[!duplicated(Coord$CLAVE),]
```

My ideal final data frame looks like this:

```
   CLAVE   NOMBRE       CVE_ENT `ENTIDAD FEDERATIVA~ CVE_MUN `MUNICIPIO (INEG~ MAPA
               
 1 03AGN-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010001
 2 03AGO-~ Agostaderito       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010094  
 3 03AGP-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010096  
 4 03AGS-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010100  
 5 03AIS-~ Alfa Nissan        1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010102  
 6 03ALF-~ Nissan Mexi~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010104  
 7 03APT-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010106  
 8 03ASS-~ Aguascalien~       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010112  
 9 03ASU-~ Asuncion           1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010113  
10 03AYU-~ Ayuntamiento       1 AGUASCALIENTES             1 AGUASCALIENTES 10010120
```

Comment: It would help if you provided data that can be loaded directly in R, such as a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two steps:

1. find matching subsets of `df1` and `df2` (what a `join` typically does)
2. bind them with `cbind()` or `bind_cols()`, since you actually don't want to do a join

To keep the matching subsets together, it's practical to use nesting.

```
library(tidyverse)
# Dummy data
df1 <- tibble(uniq_id = letters[1:10],
              id1 = rep(1:3, times = c(5,3,2)),
              id2 = rep(1:5, each = 2))

df2 <- tibble(id1 = rep(1:3, each = 15),
              id2 = rep(1:5, times = 9),
              coord = paste("coord",id1, id2, c(LETTERS, LETTERS[1:19]), sep="-"))

df1 %>%
  nest_join(df2, by = c("id1", "id2")) %>%
  nest(df1 = uniq_id) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(cbound = list(bind_cols(df1, df2[1:nrow(df1), ]))) %>%
  select(-df1, -df2) %>%
  unnest(cbound)
```

But I do have doubts about why doing that: normally a join is well-defined since you have a particular criterion to match rows in df1 to df2. Here, why should `AGN` have MAPA=10010001 and `AGO` have MAPA=10010094, and not the opposite?

## Base R solution

You can obtain the same result using a base R solution:

```
# Dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(uniq_id = letters[1:10],
              id1 = rep(1:3, times = c(5,3,2)),
              id2 = rep(1:5, each = 2))

df2 <- data.frame(id1 = rep(1:3, each = 15),
              id2 = rep(1:5, times = 9))
df2$coord <- paste("coord",df2$id1, df2$id2, c(LETTERS, LETTERS[1:19]), sep="-")

parallel_merge <- function(xy){
  x <- xy[1]
  y <- xy[2]
  df1_rows <- which(df1$id1 == x & df1$id2 == y)
  
  if(length(df1_rows) == 0) return(NULL)

  df2_rows <- which(df2$id1 == x & df2$id2 == y)
  df2_rows <- df2_rows[1:length(df1_rows)]
  
  cbind(df1[df1_rows,],
        df2[df2_rows,])
}

combinations <- expand.grid(unique(df1$id1), unique(df2$id2))

coords_by_comb <- apply(combinations, 1, parallel_merge)
do.call(rbind, coords_by_comb)
```

The logic is slightly different: we first use `expand.grid()` to generate every combination of `id1` and `id2`, then we can use `apply()` to loop on these combinations (note that if it some combinations do not exist in `df1`, this is not an optimal solution). For each combination, in the function `parallel_merge()`, we find the subset of `df1` to keep, the subset of `df2` to keep and truncate it to match `df1`. Then we just need to assemble everything.

Comment: I am trying to run it with the dummy df's and with my own and I keep getting this error: 
`Error in 1:nrow(df1) : argument of length 0`

Comment: Try running parts of the pipe to find which step creates the error: I imagine this happens at the `mutate` step? Does it happen with the dummy data I included in my answer? Else, can you edit your question to provide a minimal dataset that reproduces that error? Does it still happen in a newly started R session? (I edited my answer to include the library call)?

Comment: yes, it is in the  `mutate` step and it happens with the dummy data you included in your answer. I did restart my R session, called tidyverse and I am getting the same result. I am wondering if it is because it is a tibble and not a data frame

Comment: Can you run `sessionInfo()` and report the version of `R`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`?

Comment: `R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)`
`dplyr_1.0.1`
`tidyr_1.1.1`

Comment: Strange, it works on my computer with the same versions (except dplyr 1.0.2). I edited my answer to include a base R solution, see if that works.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfect. I am doing this arbitrary join since I know these unique ID's are in a same region but at different geographical points. So although it is arbitrary, I know for sure these are within a same region